# Copy PS2 memory cards into PCSX2 emulator

Tags: emulation, ps2, pcsx2

Okay, I have the following:

- PS2 memory cards with saves from PS2
- PS2 memory card adapter for PS3
- PS3 which can read those files
- No PS2 or fat PS3 anymore, which is why I use...
- PCSX2 emulator which I want to be able to access those files

Now, I would have thought this would make copying PS2 save files to my PC in a format PCSX2 can read would be a simple task, but apparently not. I haven't found PC drivers for the PS2 card adapter (amazingly, it's USB and it seems prime for hacking), so instead I copied over the PS2 saves from the PS3 onto a thumbstick as .PSV files.

I found a utility called PSV Exporter which eats PSV Files and spits out...other files I don't really know what to do with. I also have MyMC and PS2 Save Builder which are supposed to operate on PS2 save files, but neither seems to know what to do with the files output by PSV exporter.

So, given my equipment or a simply a PSV file, what software do I need to copy my "real" PS2 saves into some format PCSX2 can read?

Answer (score 3):

Found it on:
http://mmorpggamerz.blogspot.ro/p/how-to-convert-psv-to-pcsx2-format.html

Here are the steps in the guide.

You need the following: MyMcConverter, PSV Exporter, PS2 Save Builder (the blog provides links to these).

1. Download/have PS3 saves (i.e. .psv format)
2. Unzip that download to a directory
3. Use PSVExporter and "Open" one of the .psv files from step 2
4. Extract all files to a specified location
5. Use PS2 Save builder, drag and drop the 3( or more i dunno ) files extracted in step
6. **IMPORTANT**: Set the Root/ID to the directory in which the save games were located in Step 4, 
   e.g. "BESLES-54354FF1222"
7. Select "File\Save As" in PS2 Save builder, give it a filename e.g. "FF12newsave" and save as format X-Port 2(*.xps)
8. Open "mymc-gui.exe" , select your PCSX2 memory card( in the memcards directory where you      installed PCSX2 ), select mcd001.ps2
9. Click import and select file from step 7. You should see the save icon on the right
10. Load up F12 or whatever, select the memory card and load and away you go